# Selenium Webdriver C# - redirect chromedriver.log to stdout or stderr

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to redirect Chromedriver logs from saving to *chromedriver.log* to stdout, as it's done in Geckodriver and MSEdgeDriver, so that I can view the logs in build logs of CI (TeamCity). As mentioned in the title, I'm using C# bindings. My current code is

```
private IWebDriver ResolveChromeDriver()
    {
        var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        service.EnableVerboseLogging = true;

        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Driver, LogLevel.All);
        options.AddArgument("--verbose");

        return new ChromeDriver(service, options);
    }
```

It doesn't work though. Is there any other way to perform it?